# Dynamically access Vue component data variable names

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

edit: I have used a number in this example which was a bad idea, in the real program I'm not using numbers but names (eg name_abba, name_jef, name_john)

I have 4 variables in my Vue component:

```
name_1
name_2
name_3
number
```

Printing the values is done as such:

```
{{ name_1 }}
```

How can I change the number in back of the variable, based on the value of the variable `number`?
Or is there a better way to make something like this work?

```
{{ name_{{number}} }}
```

Comment: Any time you have variables with a numeric suffix you probably wanted an array.

Comment: In the example I'm using a number, in the actual code I'm not using numbers :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `$data` option:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      name_abba: 'aaa',
      name_jef: 'bbb',
      name_john: 'ccc',
      current: 'john'
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  {{ $data[`name_${current}`] }}
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.14/vue.min.js"></script>
```

It would be better to place your variables in an object instead of on the root so that you don't have to use `$data`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      current: 'john',
      name: {
        abba: 'aaa',
        jef: 'bbb',
        john: 'ccc',
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  {{ name[current] }}
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.14/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Maybe using a number as example was a bad idea, a more accurate example would be variables: "name_jef" and "name_john" and the parts "jef" and "john" would be stored in variable "extra". How could I achieve name_{extra} ?

Comment: My answer already works for strings too.  Did you try it?  I've changed my examples to make this exceptionally clear.

Comment: I've indeed managed to get it to work. Even tho it's probably not the perfect solution, it's the best I could think of for my edge case (the example is way to generic). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Array is more effiency your example. You can also use with Array v-for, Filter And Find methods. Also search in array or change names, split or splice.

```js
<div id="app">
  {{ names[number-1] }} <!-- Result =name2. if you need name 2 array index = 1    -->
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      number: 2,
      names: ['name1','name2','name3'],
      }
    }
  }
});
```